# Bootstrap tooltip within modal form label tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to have text inside a label have a hover-over tooltip associated with it. I'm not certain it's the label tag that is causing the issue but I know that if I move to tooltip outside of the label, it works. Here's a code snippet:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3" style="margin-left: 2%;" 
    for="endpointname">Name: 
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The endpoint name should reflect the name of the application"></i></label> 
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="z-index: 999;">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endptname"
            name="endptname" onchange="endptNameEntered()"
            placeholder="Enter name" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I've seen other posts about adding a javascript function to enable tooltips but tooltips located elsewhere on the page work and, as I mentioned, it works in this modal if I just move the tooltip outside of the label. I've also removed the z-index in case that was the issue but no joy.

Sorry if this is obvious/already answered but I'm not getting it. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your code to include a complete, reproducible example. You should show the markup for all the parent elements of your example, the exact version of bootstrap resources and how you implement them as well as any additional css or scripts affecting the element or any of its ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

As it states in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/tooltips/#overview):

> Tooltips are opt-in for performance reasons, so **you must initialize them yourself**.

Add the following bit of javascript to the end of your page after including bootstrap.js and before the closing `</body>` tag and your code should work as expected:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/rqcmzyxL/).

Comment: For whatever reason, this doesn't work for me. As I said, tooltips do work on the modal outside of the label tag. When I add in the function you mentioned, tooltips on the page but not in the modal have to be dismissed. But the one inside the label still doesn't appear. I see it works in your example so I have some conflict or something in my modal. I'll keep trying .

Comment: @Brutus is the model content present in the DOM on page load or is it getting added later? For tooltip elements added after page load you will need to call the above function again.

Comment: It's present on page load. Can you think of alternatives to tooltip that gives the same functionality? I even tried changing the tooltip to a button so I could pop a modal when it was clicked but as long the button was within in the label tags, it didn't work. Thanks.